# Item becomes disabled when removing it from listView

Tags: android

My application consists of an Activity and a background service (`IntentService`). The activity contains a `listView`. I want to remove the first item from the list when an event occurs in the servie. My code is:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView taskListBox;
    private static ArrayAdapter taskListAdapter;
    private static ArrayList<String> data =
            new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        taskListBox = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskList);
        taskListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, data);
        taskListBox.setAdapter(taskListAdapter);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        ...
    }

    public static void removeTask(int index) {
        data.remove(index);
        taskListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

List is populated in `onResume` method and every thing works fine. Items are selectable and contextMenu pops up on long click on the items, but problem occurs when I call `removeTask` from service class, that is the items become disabled (not selectable). My service class is:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            try {
                if (MyActivity.dateNow().compareTo(MyActivity.futureDate()) >= 0) {
                    MyActivity.removeTask(0);
                }
            }catch(Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure that the `if` block in `MyService` is executed, but item does not get removed from the list and it becomes just like disabled item. Clicking the item does not work. Can someone point out the problem in this code?

Comment: It would help to see the custom adapter that you set on the list.

Comment: For now, the list is populated with simple strings, using `taskListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, data)`

Comment: It;s important what you've overridden in that adapter not what it currently uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't share data (and methods) between an 'Activity' and a 'Service by using static modifiers. This is generally a bad idea, because you introduce synchronization issues between the 2 process.

The proper way to do what you are trying to do is the bind the 'MyActivity' to 'MyService'

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) to see how to setup a bind between a service and an activity.

Once that is done, you should create a call back method in your activity that the service can call. In your case 'removeTask' will be the callback method that the service will call.

Comment: I now used a `BroadcastReceiver` in my activity, sending a broadcast message from service from `if` block and calling the `removeTask` method in `onReceive()` method. Thank you.